# An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, exception

hello i'm trying to consume a rest web service and expose it in chtml but  i keep getting this error when i launch my application and i don't understand it . is it because of a missing library or dependency?

Absencecontroller :

```
using ProjectWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace ProjectWeb.Controllers
{
    public class AbsenceController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Absence
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpClient Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:18080/PiDev-web/rest/absence/");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync("all").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ViewBag.result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Absence>>().Result;
                ///ViewBag.result1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.result = "error";
            }

            return View("index");
        }

        // GET: Absence/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Absence/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Absence/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Absence/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Absence/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Absence/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Absence/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My index.chtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h3>
        @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter Absence ", "Create")
    </h3>
    <hr />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nom</th>

            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var h in ViewBag.result)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@h.idAbsence</td>
                <td>@h.cause</td>



            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = h.idAbsence }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = h.idAbsence }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = h.idAbsence })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }


    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and when i launch it by pressing on view on browser i get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwgZw.png)

and when i press on it the error i s caused by :

> ```
>  ViewBag.result =response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Absence().Result;
> ```

please if you re familiar with this error help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case an AggregateException probably means a task threw an exception. You can turn on the "Break On All Exceptions" under debug options and run again to find out the original exception.

oh and unselect "Enable Just My Code"

Answer (score 0):

I just run in the same exception;
The content headers contains Content-Type=application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1

response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() is working fine and gets my umlaut 'é'

but
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Data_kunder>>() just throws System.AggregateException with inner exception
DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [E5] at index 562 from specified code page to Unicode.

Looks like a Microsoft bug. Workaround would be to use ReadAsStringAsync first then parse json afterwards